# Installing Yarn through Bash shell WSL1

Tags: bash, ubuntu, installation, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run curl, it shows this error:

```
~$ curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
```

I'm unable to install yarn.

I tried killing:

```
~$ kill -9 gpg-agent
```

and restarting:

```
~$ gpg-agent --daemon
```

but nothing worked so far. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I did this from my root -

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Checked if the yarn is installed by -

```
yarn --version
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove gnupg
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install gnupg1
```

This installs GNUPG Classic. Read more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/655246/are-gnupg-1-and-gnupg-2-compatible-with-each-other).